# Question on stochastic process

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\pi)$ be a probability space with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ and measure $\pi$. Let 
$$X:[0,+\infty)\times \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
a family of random variables such that $\forall t\in [0,+\infty)$ the function $X(t,\cdot)\in L^{1}(\Omega)$. I know moreover that: 
$$\int_{\Omega}X( t,\omega )\,d\pi(\omega)=0 \qquad \forall t\in [0,+\infty)\,;$$

for $s,t\in [0,+\infty)$ with $s\neq t$
$$\int_{\Omega}X( t,\omega )X( s,\omega )\,d\pi(\omega)=0\,;$$

random variables $X(t,\cdot)$ are equidistributed. I want to prove that it can't happen that for almost every $ \omega\in \Omega$ the function $X(\cdot,\omega)\in C^{0}([0,+\infty),\mathbb{R})$. If $X(t,\cdot)\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ it's ok, it follows easily from dominated convergence theorem applied to
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow t}\int_{\Omega}X( t,\omega )X( s,\omega )\,d\pi(\omega)\,.$$
 But how can i prove it if i don't assume $X(t,\cdot)\in L^{2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: If the random variables are not in $L^2$ how do you define $\int_{\Omega}X( t,\omega )X( s,\omega )\,d\pi(\omega)$?

Comment: it's an assumption, i know that the function $X(t,\omega)X(s,\omega)\in L^{1}$